# PHP Foreach query checking

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cart_id] => 24763
            [product_id] => 740
            [name] => Samsung S20
            [model] => Samsung S20
            [shipping] => 1
            [image] => catalog/samsung/samsungs20.jpg
            [option] => Array
                (
                )

            [download] => Array
                (
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cart_id] => 24799
            [product_id] => 749
            [name] => Huawei P40
            [model] => Huawei P40
            [shipping] => 1
            [image] => catalog/huawei/huaweip40.jpg
            [option] => Array
                (
                )

            [download] => Array
                (
                )
        )

)
```

^ Above is the output of the array

```
$productdata = $this->cart->getProducts();
```

^ Above is the code for query out array

> is there anyway to check product_id of each array ? Let say that if
> product_id = 749 , alert ('P40');

Tried to do

```
foreach ($productdata as $productdatas) {
    if ($productdata['product_id'] = 749)
    { alert('P40'); 
    }

}
```

nothing happen

Comment: Where is your foreach?

Comment: The code you say you tried has syntax errors so it won't run at all. Please read this to see how to make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see the problem and be able to help.

Comment: @catcon added in first post

Comment: @FluffyKitten found it when editing , fixed and still same thing

Comment: Take a look at the variables you use in `foreach` and then look at which of these variables you use to check the product id... do you see the problem now?

Comment: @FluffyKitten my bad , its working now , look like a mistake that shouldn't happen. 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part *sets* the key, not read it. You need to replace the `=` with `==`:

```php
// From
if ($productdata['product_id'] = 749)

// To
if ($productdata['product_id'] == 749)
```